# Proving that $S_3$ is isomorphic to symmetries of the equilateral triangle

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

I'm trying to prove that $S_3 \cong D_3$. One approach is writing out the multiplication tables. Another is to prove that $D_3$ is non-abelian and that any non-abelian group of order $6$ is isomorphic to $S_3$. I'm curious of whether this approach would also work.

The definition of $S_3$ is Artin is the group generated by $x = (123)$ and $y = (12)$ satisfying $x^3 = 1$, $y^2 = 1$, and $yx = x^2 y$. I'm thinking that I can define a map that sends generators of $S_3$ to generators of $D_3$ and then verify that the defining relations are satisfied. For example, I would send $(123)$ to the rotation $r$, a counterclockwise rotation by $\frac{2\pi}{3}$, and $(12)$ to a fixed reflection, $s$, let's say that reflection through the vertex at the apex of the triangle. (I'm not sure of a better way to describe it without a picture.)

I would show that $r^3 = 1$ and $s^2 = 1$, which are certainly true since the rotation has order $3$ and any reflection has order $2$, followed by the fact that $sr = r^2 s$, which is less obvious, but certainly true (by induction). Is that enough? Sending generators to generators certainly uniquely defines a map, and showing that the defining relations are respected under the map gives a homomorphism. I haven't established that there is a bijective correspondence. Is it as simple as recognizing that $|S_3| = |D_3| = 6$?

I'd appreciate any help with this argument. If it's on track, I'd appreciate help with making it more rigorous.

Comment: I think you need to give your definition of $D_3$.  Your definition of $S_3$ seems strange. It is usually defined to be the group of all permutations of a set of size $3$.

Comment: @DerekHolt I agree with that definition, though I believe Artin gives the presentation $S_3$ as the set of elements generated by $(123)$ and $(12)$, so I was trying to use those defining relations in the proof. The only comparable definition of $D_3$ I'm able to find is the group generated by a reflection by $\frac{2\pi}{n}$ and a reflection.